# Display pictures in a TableView from Firebase Storage in SWIFT without mistake

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I have a chat app where people can talk in a group and a little picture is displayed in each cell to show who is talking. I managed to display these pictures from Firebase storage but it is not always the right picture which is displayed at the right place.

It only works when I go to the previous View Controller and coming back the chat View to see the pictures displayed properly in each cell.

I tried override prepareForReuse() but it's not better. Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem ?

```
import UIKit


class CustomMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var messageBody: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet weak var messageBubble : UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageBodyTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var userPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
     messageBubble.layer.cornerRadius = messageBubble.frame.size.height / 5
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
 }
    
   

  
      override func prepareForReuse() {
         super.prepareForReuse()
                      
            userPicture.image = nil 
            messageBodyTextView.text = ""
            usernameLabel.text = ""
            timeLabel.text = ""
        
  print("prepareforreuse")

    }
  }
```

for the class ConversationViewController

```
class ConversationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    
  //  ...



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 
    let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell
    
    cell.userPicture.image = nil

    cell.selectionStyle = .none


   //...

        
        cell.messageBodyTextView.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].messageBody
        cell.usernameLabel.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.timeLabel.text = dateToShow
        
        
       
        cell.userPicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userPicture.frame.height / 2
        cell.userPicture.clipsToBounds = true

        // Charge image
                 
        
                   let imagePath = self.storageRef.reference(withPath:"\(message.uid)/resizes/profilImage_150x150.jpg")
                  
                  imagePath.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                                                                                                                          
                                 if let error = error {
                                                     
                             cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: "emptyProfilPic")
                                                                                                                              
                             print("Got an error fetching data : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                                                                                              
                               //  return
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       }

                                 
                             if let data = data {
                                                                    
                           cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                                                   
                                            }
                                              
                              }
        return cell
    }
```

}

Comment: To confirm, the issue isn't that no picture is showing, it is that the WRONG one shows?

Comment: Yes , I confirm that there is always a picture shown in each cell , but it's not always the right one.